# Handling Massive MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have just been asked to fix our address DB in work as it is very slow, i don't normaly go near it as another guy looks after it but he has left now so its down to me.

problem is the DB contains 5 tables and a lot of information is replicated in each table there should be 27 million rows however there are 30 million rows so there are over 3 million rows repeated, and the way our old IT guy had it setup was when there was a query it would search all 5 tables an he used a php script to weed out the duplicate rows so information was only shown once. and this is slowing our server down considerably, so I wrote a php script to take each row an compare it against the 30 million others and if there was a duplicate to delete it, however 2 mins after i started it the server crashed so i tried a few other scripts using php however every time i try to run a complex mysql query the server crashes.

Is there an easy way that won't crash the server to merge all the tables an delete all the duplicated entries?

Copy of the DB

```
post1           10,044,279   MyISAM    latin1_german2_ci   758.1 MiB   -
post2            8,328,333   MyISAM    latin1_german2_ci   624.7 MiB   -
postcode         9,344,317   MyISAM    latin1_german2_ci   703.8 MiB   -
postcode_nw      1,157,217   InnoDB    utf8_unicode_ci      97.6 MiB   -
postcode_tmp     1,749,650   MyISAM    latin1_german2_ci    50.5 MiB   -
```

Comment: your description shows a pretty bad DB design

Comment: We'd need the table schemas to have a prayer of helping you, and do you have the leeway to change them? Personally I wouldn't even try to do this in place, I'd create a new db, set up some tables, and then start moving data across.

Comment: If you only need to do this once, you can create a 6th table with the proper index to prevent duplicates - then insert records from the other 5 tables into the 6th one table at a time. Just insert records into the 6th where they don't already exist. You probably want the same index you created in the 6th table in the 5 original tables, just not set as unique.

Comment: Do you know why your server is crashing? Presumably you mean your database server. I would fix this first - although it sounds like your database design could be improved, you need to get what you have working first, if only to compare the before-and-after of improved designs.

Comment: (Incidentally - questions benefit enormously by having short, readable sentences and paragraphing. Para 2 here could use a few pauses for breath ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem with PHP developers is they forget there is such a thing as memory in computers.
It "smells" as if you tried to load everything into the memory.
Your approach was actually the right one, it will be very slow, but safe. **If** you implement it correctly.
You do not care about speed as it is a one time thing.

1. Design your code in such a way it handles small batches of data
2. manually clean after yourself (assign null where needed, make the GC work, wait until GC does it stuff between each iteration).
3. Consider doing it as a SP, and use a cursor in the SP (google it).
4. After you clean your data, I would recommend to analyze your db structure and migrate it it to a more robust structure (i.e. normalize it).
5. consider other methods of storing some of the data, nothing wrong fopr example to store huge texts as files and only pointers to them in the DB. If those texts needs to be search-able (i.e. a full text thingy) MySql is not the best tool for that (Google SOLR for example).
6. Oh...InnoDB is better than the old and almost not-developed-anymore MyIssam

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can give a definitive answer but I can give you some suggestions:

1. The server probably crashes because it's running out of memory. Adding memory to it or perhaps uploading the database to a temporary AWS server with larger memory to run your complex queries might do the trick.
2. You could consider using simple queries to fetch the data and compare it on a remote computer instead of letting the server do the heavy work. It will take longer, but it will eventually get the job done.
3. Perhaps you could change your older php script that weeds out the duplicates and have it remove the duplicates instead of just not showing them. Will not go thru all data, but it will eventually reduce the duplicates. This approach could then be modified so this older php script could be invoked by a loop thru all data so it will catch the duplicates that were not caught by the normal operation clean-up code.